# Going all over a list and checking if boolean property are in the list

Tags: c#, linq, list, extension-methods, conditional-statements

I'm coding a battleship in console mode with C#.
When I drop my boats they cross over each other so I have a class cases (mean square of the playing board) and a Listposition which contain a boolean proprety `Used`.

Here's a part of the code:

```
bool isok;
do
{
    isok = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Donner la position du haut de votre " + bat.Name + " en X");
    int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Donner la position du haut du navire en Y");
    int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Positionnement Vertical (1) ou Horizontal (2) ");                  
    int direction = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var essay = b1.Position.Select(e=>e.Used);

    bool overlap = false;
    for (int i = y; i <= y + bat.Size - 1; i++)
        overlap = overlap || b1.Position.Exists(c => c.Y == y && c.X == x && c.Used);

    switch (direction)
    {
        case 2:
        {
            if ((y + bat.Size - 1 > 9) || overlap)
            {
                isok = false;
            }  

            {
                isok = false;
            }  
            else
            {
                for (int i = y; i <= y + bat.Size-1 ; i++)
                {

                    b1.Position.Add(new cases(x, i, true, false, false, false));
                    b1.changetype(x, i);
                    b1.changeUsed(x, i);
                    b2.changetype(x, i);

                }
            }       
            break;
        }
    }
}

public cases(int x , int y, bool target, bool touch, bool played, bool used)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.target = target;
    this.touch = touch;
    this.played = played;
    this.used = used;
}

public void changetype(int x,int y)
{           
        vue[x, y].Target = true;
}

public void changeUsed(int x, int y)
{
    vue[x, y].Used = true;
}

public List<cases> Position
{
    get
    {
        return position;
    }
    set
    {
        position = value;
    }
}
```

It's in French but it's just asking to enter two coordinates (x and y) to get the place of the starting case of the boat. My question is which extensible method I can use in my `if` condition? I want in fact that the list being read before the boat is placed there is a hold in the if line help me to fill in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think List.Exists() is what you are looking for.

Position.Exists(c => c.used)

Edit:
I think you'll need a for loop before the if statement that records if there are any overlaps.

```
bool overlap = false;
for (int i = y; i <= y + bat.Size-1; i++)
    overlap = overlap || Position.Exists(c => c.y == y && c.x == x && c.used);
```

After that, use overlap in the if condition.

Edit:
I made a mistake with the loop.

```
bool overlap = false;
for (int i = y; i <= y + bat.Size-1; i++)
    overlap = overlap || Position.Exists(c => c.y == i && c.x == x && c.used);
```

What this code is doing is that it checks if any space that your boat needs is already in use and records if it is. If it's easier for you to read, this is the same as the above:

```
bool overlap = false;
for (int i = y; i <= y + bat.Size-1; i++)
    if (Position.Exists(c => c.y == i && c.x == x && c.used))
        overlap = true;
```

Also, this code should be inside case 2 and before the if statement.

Comment: i tryed but my boats are still crossing over maybe i m not using it well?

Comment: thank you but i don't understand the code you wrote 
overlap is just a boolean so it s true or false 
 idon't understand de bouble pipe its not a "or"?
i copy paste but still not working

Comment: The double pipe is an or. You put this code above the if statement and change the if statement to if ((y + bat.Size-1 > 9) || overlap)

Comment: I try this way but it s still not working but my boat are compose with many cases so even if you check the first one overlap has only one value the test should be done on many cases so i understant de for loop but its not recording all the position in an only one variable

Comment: i almost understood but shouldn't i put in the condition line c.Used == true ? And in the second condition the one i must use the overlap is that
    if ((y + bat.Size - 1 > 9) || overlap) 
enough ?

Comment: that s work now i forgot to change the boo whe i was adding in the position list thank you so much D